# Reading expandable hdf5 dataset (written in c++) in python

Tags: python, c++, pandas, hdf5

In my current Project, I am supposed to loop trough data and save the results in .h5 files. Since I am looping through a huge amount of data, saving everything at once is not an option.
I have to admit that I do not fully understand the hdf5 documentation, but from what I've got from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HDFGroup/hdf5/develop/c++/examples/h5tutr_extend.cpp) and [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/extend_ds_8cpp-example.html#_a1), the following code should work.
The idea here is, that I create a dataset and expand it by adding different sets of data. This is, of course, just a code-snipped.
However, I get the same problem when trying to read the files produced in the provided links, so maybe I am misunderstanding something?

```cpp
#include "H5Cpp.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct SquareInformation{
    float a;
    float b;
};

SquareInformation firstset[] = {
        { 18.5, 15},
        { 22.5, 2.5 }
    };
SquareInformation secondset[] = {
        { 22, 122.0}
    };

const hsize_t ndims = 2;
const hsize_t ncols = 4;
const int      RANK = 2;


int main(){
    // defining the datatype to pass HDF55
    H5::CompType mtype(sizeof(SquareInformation));
    mtype.insertMember("a",   HOFFSET(SquareInformation, a), H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);
    mtype.insertMember("b",  HOFFSET(SquareInformation, b), H5::PredType::NATIVE_FLOAT);

    
    // preparation of a dataset and a file.
    H5::H5File file = H5::H5File("sets.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    
    //Unlimited 2D dataspace
    hsize_t      dims[2]  = { 0,ncols};  // dataset dimensions at creation
    hsize_t      maxdims[2] = {H5S_UNLIMITED, H5S_UNLIMITED};
    H5::DataSpace mspace1( RANK, dims, maxdims);
    std::cout << "- Dataspace created" << std::endl;
    
    /*
    * Modify dataset creation properties, i.e. enable chunking.
    */
    H5::DSetCreatPropList cparms;
    hsize_t      chunk_dims[2] = {1, 1000000};
    cparms.setChunk( RANK, chunk_dims );

    /*
    * Set fill value for the dataset
    */
    int fill_val = 0;
    cparms.setFillValue( mtype, &firstset);

    H5::DataSet squares = H5::DataSet(file.createDataSet("figures.h5", mtype, mspace1, cparms));
    hsize_t      size[2];
    size[0]   = 1;
    size[1]   = ncols;
    squares.extend(size);

    H5::DataSpace fspace1 = squares.getSpace ();
    hsize_t     offset[2];
    offset[0] = 0;
    offset[1] = 0;
    hsize_t      dims1[2] = { 0, ncols};            /* data1 dimensions */
    fspace1.selectHyperslab( H5S_SELECT_SET, dims1, offset );

    squares.write(firstset, mtype, mspace1, fspace1);


    //delete squares;
    //delete file;

    return 0;
}
```

When I do it like this, the code compiles and runs, so great so far.
I run this code using

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lhdf5 -lhdf5_cpp
```

My problem now is that I am unable to read the resulting file in a python juypter notebook.
When I try

```py
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = "figures.h5"
with h5py.File(test, "r") as f:
    # List all groups
    print("Keys: %s" % f.keys())
    a_group_key = list(f.keys())[0]
```

I still get a list of keys:

```
Keys: <KeysViewHDF5 ['squares']>
```

When trying to access the data in `squares` with

```
df_test = pd.read_hdf(test, key="squares")
```

I get the following error message:

```
HDF5ExtError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e43b264294b5> in <module>
----> 1 df_test = pd.read_hdf(test, key="squares")

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, errors, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, **kwargs)
    413                     )
    414             key = candidate_only_group._v_pathname
--> 415         return store.select(
    416             key,
    417             where=where,

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in select(self, key, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, auto_close)
    865         )
    866 
--> 867         return it.get_result()
    868 
    869     def select_as_coordinates(

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in get_result(self, coordinates)
   1919 
   1920         # directly return the result
-> 1921         results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
   1922         self.close()
   1923         return results

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in func(_start, _stop, _where)
    849         # function to call on iteration
    850         def func(_start, _stop, _where):
--> 851             return s.read(start=_start, stop=_stop, where=_where, columns=columns)
    852 
    853         # create the iterator

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in read(self, where, columns, start, stop)
   4472             return None
   4473 
-> 4474         result = self._read_axes(where=where, start=start, stop=stop)
   4475 
   4476         info = (

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in _read_axes(self, where, start, stop)
   3672         # create the selection
   3673         selection = Selection(self, where=where, start=start, stop=stop)
-> 3674         values = selection.select()
   3675 
   3676         results = []

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py in select(self)
   5194         elif self.coordinates is not None:
   5195             return self.table.table.read_coordinates(self.coordinates)
-> 5196         return self.table.table.read(start=self.start, stop=self.stop)
   5197 
   5198     def select_coords(self):

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tables/table.py in read(self, start, stop, step, field, out)
   1927                                                 warn_negstep=False)
   1928 
-> 1929         arr = self._read(start, stop, step, field, out)
   1930         return internal_to_flavor(arr, self.flavor)
   1931 

~/.local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tables/table.py in _read(self, start, stop, step, field, out)
   1841             # This optimization works three times faster than
   1842             # the row._fill_col method (up to 170 MB/s on a pentium IV @ 2GHz)
-> 1843             self._read_records(start, stop - start, result)
   1844         # Warning!: _read_field_name should not be used until
   1845         # H5TBread_fields_name in tableextension will be finished

tables/tableextension.pyx in tables.tableextension.Table._read_records()

HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5Dio.c", line 199, in H5Dread
    can't read data
  File "H5Dio.c", line 487, in H5D__read
    src and dest dataspaces have different number of elements selected

End of HDF5 error back trace

Problems reading records.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: When Pandas saves a data frame to HDF5, the resulting file has a particular format. That is, the groups and datasets have certain names. As a consequence, when reading an HDF5 file Pandas expects the same names and structure. In short, not every HDF5 file can be opened by Pandas. My advice is to to read the data using only the `h5py` package. This will give you regular Numpy arrays. Then see if you can make Pandas objects by passing these arrays to the dataframe constructor. If you still get an error reading the file with `h5py`, at least it will give you more details on which data set fails.

Comment: you are right @titusjan , that was indeed the problem. Everything works now. Thank you!